# Objective C can i use ANSI library if i want to run my application in iOS?

Tags: ios

bare with my basic question. I m basically from a C/C++ background. And i would like to develop a parser for particular data formation in iOS, and send few information after parsing to UI. I already have the parsing login in C, My question is , can i use the same code in Objective-C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Objective-C is a strict superset of C, any and all C code is valid Objective-C code, so the answer is yes.

Comment: Thanks, in that case why we need Objective-C?. it is only usable when i do GUI programming?

Comment: Well, you need Objective-C if you want to use frameworks written in Objective-C, like UIKit and Foundation. You can write anything else in C, though. If you prefer C++, you can use Objective-C++ which is Objective-C with C++.

Comment: @Whoami You can use objective-c if you would benefit from using Object-Oriented Programming, even when there isn't a GUI involved. If you designed the complete solution in C, that's awesome and works too.

Comment: If you like OOP for some reason you could use Objective-C or C++ instead of C. Anyway, you need either Objective-C or Objective-C++ if you want to use UIKit; I'm not aware of any wrapper around UIKit that's written in C or C++.